# Apple push notification get an error Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I get the follwoing error "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

after the ling code:
stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);

It poined to a valid p.12

```
void connect()
        {
            client = new TcpClient();

            //Notify we are connecting
            var eoc = this.OnConnecting;
            if (eoc != null)
                eoc(this.appleSettings.Host, this.appleSettings.Port);

            try
            {
                client.Connect(this.appleSettings.Host, this.appleSettings.Port);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ConnectionFailureException("Connection to Host Failed", ex);
            }

            if (appleSettings.SkipSsl)
            {
                networkStream = client.GetStream();
            }
            else
            {
                stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
                    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }),
                    new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback((sender, targetHost, localCerts, remoteCert, acceptableIssuers) =>
                    {
                        return certificate;
                    }));

                try
                {
                    stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
                    //stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host);
                }
                catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
                {
                    throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream Failed to Authenticate as Client", ex);
                }

                if (!stream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated)
                    throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream Failed to Authenticate", null);

                if (!stream.CanWrite)
                    throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream is not Writable", null);

                networkStream = stream;
            }

            //Start reading from the stream asynchronously
            Reader();
        }

    }
```

Comment: have the same problem. any clue?

Comment: What certificate did you use? I'm trying to do the same thing here but I am not sure I have the correct cert

Answer (score 4):

```
stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
```

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a

Apple push servers no longer supports SSL3. Try change this to .Default or .TLS and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Moon API for .NET and change Protocol Ssl3 to Tls as Above 
and used .p12 file instead of .pem
.p12 is generated using fallowing certificates.

$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in chatPushCert.pem -inkey chatPushKey.pem -certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -name "apn_developer_identity" -out apn_developer_identity.p12

and every thing working very fine.

Comment: I downloaded the Moon Api too but alse there I get: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. Any idea? I used the Code Signing Certificate from the Apple server, is that the correct one'?

Comment: have you generated  above certificates if yes then use this inside .Net developer process as moon API Guide line and change Protocol Ssl3 to Tls .

Comment: I extracted the p12 file from keychain on the apple server instead of using openssl

Comment: Its working indeed. Some upvotes for your help, Thanks. Final question, do you have any info on dinfing the device Token? Regards

Comment: actually you can't define any token for your device, apple server will assign device token to your device for that you have to place  following code  into your AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString *token=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"devicetoken"];
   
}

Comment: this function call if you have successfully resisted for push notification and you will receive your device token..and add notification permission code   to 'same file in didfinishlosding function '.here i am unable to post code you can find by googling it.